# Why I should prefer either Maybe type over question mark or vise versa?

Tags: typescript

To define class property as optional I can use question mark or `Maybe` type `type Maybe<T> = T | undefined`

```
class Animal {
  mouth: Maybe<Mouth>
}
```

or

```
class Animal {
  mouth?: Mouth
}
```

Is there a difference?

Comment: There is no difference.

Comment: @RobertoZvjerković there is difference: in the first case it's guaranteed the value has the `mouth` key, in the second - not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that optional field allows for not having the field at all, where `T | undefined` forces to have a field with explicit `undefined` or `T`. Check below difference:

```
{
// explicit undefined version
type Maybe<T> = T | undefined
type Mouth = {test:string}
class Animal {
  mouth: Maybe<Mouth>
}

const animal: Animal = { } // error
const animal2: Animal = {
  mouth: undefined
} // fine as it is explicit undefined


}
// optional field version
type Maybe<T> = T | undefined
type Mouth = {test:string}
class Animal {
  mouth?: Mouth
}

const animal: Animal = { } // fine
const animal2: Animal = {
  mouth: undefined
} // fine
```

This clearly shows that `mouth?` is more wide definition in terms of the the possible values than `mouth: Mouth | undefined`. `field?` makes object without the field to be assignable to the defined type, where explicit `undefined` forces to deal with the `field`.

What to choose? It depends but in most cases optional field is the way to go, as it is less restrictive for assignability. The use case for explicit `undefined` would be some operation where we enumerate over object keys, or for example we want to tell that this field was cleared in let say PATCH request. Probably we can find more use cases for that but cannot find them in my head now.

BTW. Common construct know as Maybe type is disjoint union, and not simple union. So the definition can look like that:

```
type Maybe<T> = {tag:"just", value:T} | {tag:"nothing"}
```

More common name for `T | undefined` or `T | null` would be Nullable. But this is another topic.

Answer (score 0):

Both will have an **optional** type but for `Maybe<>` you have to unwrap the value safely to get a guaranteed value. So I would suggest you to use the `?` for **optional** values in your code.

Comment: "you have to unwrap the value safely to get a guaranteed value" --- what exactly does this mean? If it's not undefined - it's exactly `T`, no need to "unwrap" anything.

Comment: What do you mean by unwrap?